# Register custom REST routes while building a plugin for Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, php, routing

I am building a custom plugin for Craft and I am hitting some REST APIs in my backend service to fetch some data using Ajax calls in JS. What I would like to do when the AJAX calls complete and come back with data, is to store some data in Craft. I know I can use projectConfig to store and retrieve plugin based data and settings but how to call those Craft functions through my JS files. The way I figured is to call it using REST routes that I can define via my plugin.

But I am not sure how to register routes using my plugin and how to setup controllers for the same.

Main plugin file:

```
Event::on(UrlManager::class, UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES, function(RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {
            $event->rules['poptin/signup'] = 'poptin/default/signup';
        });
```

DefaultController.php

```
<?php
/**
 * poptin plugin for Craft CMS 3.x
 *
 * Create advanced website popups and forms, and improve your website's conversion rate within a few minutes.
 *
 * @link      poptin.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2020 Poptin
 */

namespace poptin\poptin\controllers;

use poptin\poptin\Poptin;

use Craft;
use craft\web\Controller;

/**
 * Default Controller
 *
 * Generally speaking, controllers are the middlemen between the front end of
 * the CP/website and your plugin’s services. They contain action methods which
 * handle individual tasks.
 *
 * A common pattern used throughout Craft involves a controller action gathering
 * post data, saving it on a model, passing the model off to a service, and then
 * responding to the request appropriately depending on the service method’s response.
 *
 * Action methods begin with the prefix “action”, followed by a description of what
 * the method does (for example, actionSaveIngredient()).
 *
 * https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/controllers
 *
 * @author    Poptin
 * @package   Poptin
 * @since     1.0.0
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    // Protected Properties
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * @var    bool|array Allows anonymous access to this controller's actions.
     *         The actions must be in 'kebab-case'
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $allowAnonymous = ['index', 'signup'];

    // Public Methods
    // =========================================================================

    /**
     * Handle a request going to our plugin's index action URL,
     * e.g.: actions/poptin/default
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $result = 'Welcome to the DefaultController actionIndex() method';

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a request going to our plugin's actionDoSomething URL,
     * e.g.: actions/poptin/default/do-something
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionSignup()
    {
        $result = 'Welcome to the DefaultController actionSignup() method';

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I see this error:

[image: Error]

Comment: You are using `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` which only registers control panel routes. If you are creating a route for the outside of the control panel, you should use `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES`.

See the documentation for more information here: https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-urlmanager.html#events

Comment: So what I basically want to do is when a user clicks something on my plugin page, I want to hit that route and run some php code in craft. What should I use? `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` or `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES`

Comment: `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES` is triggered when registering URL rules for the front-end site (from the documentation link). For your scenario, that would be the correct event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost there, Craft allows registering routes for the Control Panel and the front-end of the site. You need to change `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` to `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES`.

You are listening for an event on `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` which will only register routes inside the control panel. This is useful for plugins that want to add controllers for settings and custom logic.

> The event that is triggered when registering URL rules for the control panel.

https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-urlmanager.html#events

However, in the scenario where access is needed outside of the control panel, Craft triggers the `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES`. This allows access for users that do not have control panel access (e.g. site guests and regular users).

> The event that is triggered when registering URL rules for the front-end site.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks!